# read specific line this xml?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

Is there anyway to read the specific line in this xml?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDPIg.jpg

```
                var guide = from query in dataFeed.Descendants("MaxPayne3")
                                                 select new NewGamesClass
                                                 {
                                                     GameTitle = (string)query.Element("Title"),
                                                     Gamedescription = (string)query.Element("Description"),
                                                     GameGuide = (string)query.Element("Guide")
                                                 };
                GuidesListBox.ItemsSource = guide.Where(ngc => ngc.GameGuide.StartsWith("See 'Payne In The Ass'")).Take(1);
```

this will show all guides in the xml.

This Work:

```
                var guide = from query in dataFeed.Descendants("MaxPayne3")
                                                 select new NewGamesClass
                                                 {
                                                     GameTitle = (string)query.Element("Title"),
                                                     Gamedescription = (string)query.Element("Description"),
                                                     GameGuide = (string)query.Element("Guide")
                                                 };
                //GuidesListBox.ItemsSource = guide.Where(ngc => ngc.GameGuide.StartsWith("See 'Payne In The Ass'")).Take(1);
                GuidesListBox.ItemsSource = guide.Where(ngc => ngc.GameTitle.StartsWith("Serious"));
```

So start with whatever is the first child in the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continue your statement with a where clause: (change the condition based on your needs)

```
 var guides = from query in dataFeed.Descendants("MaxPayne3")
                                             select new NewGamesClass
                                             {
                                                 GameGuide = (string)query.Element("Guide")

                                             };

AchivementsListBox.ItemsSource = guides.Where( ngc => ngc.GameGuide.StartsWith("Chapter 4:"));
```

Comment: If i do that and there is another guide that says the same it will display all of them. example: if guide 3 = story related and guide 39 = story related, it will show both guides.

Comment: If you want just one, continue with a .Take(1) statement.

Comment: Im sorry i also want to this  the Title, description and image.

Comment: In that case you can extend the NewsGamesClass and parse those properties in the "select new NewGamesClass" part.

Comment: can you please give me a example. im still fairly new at progamming and this it my first try working with xml. sorry for being a pain.

Comment: In your NewsGamesClass, add:
public string Title {get;set;}
public string Description {get;set;}
public string Image {get;set;}

And then when parsing the XML:
select new NewGamesClass
                                             {
                                                 GameGuide = (string)query.Element("Guide"),
Title = (string)query.Element("Title"),
....

                                             };

Comment: i think i got it. instead of doing it by GameGuide i do it by GameTitle and everything is fine.